# Using if / else to change image or background id size in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am just getting into Javascript and I am trying to modify mode code using if / else statements. The original code is:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){    
    document.getElementById("box").style.height= "250px";    
});
```

I tried modifying it several ways and researched as much as I could but even after many trial and error attempts I just cant figure out how to do it. So far the code I have come up with that makes the most sense to me is

```
if(document.getElementById("button1").clicked == true) {    
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";    
};
```

but that does nothing. Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i have added the answer

Comment: if .... what ? What are you trying to check?

Comment: I am just trying to make it so that if button1 is clicked it does this else if botton2 clicked it does that and so on until all 4 buttons have a designated function.

Comment: henhen see my updated code... thats your answer.. you can use switch or if else.. whatever your wish inside the function handleOnClick

Comment: Oh thank you for this. Its a little advanced for me at the moment but i will research the unknowns. I see you also put the code in 3 segments. Is it split into java, css then html?

Comment: Yes, and I can help you. Don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: okay thank you again

Answer (score -1):

there you go

```js
buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

i = 0, length = buttons.length;
for (i; i < length; i++) {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          handleOnClick(this.id);
        });
    }
};

function handleOnClick(button_id) {
  switch(button_id) {
      
      case "button1" :
        document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
      break;
      
      case "button2" :
        document.getElementById("box").style.height = "100px";
      break;
      
      default:
        //whatever not needed
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.boxclass {
width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-buttons">
<button id="button1" class="button">Change To 250</button>
<button id="button2" class="button">Change to 100</button>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="box" class="boxclass"></div>
```

Comment: The only change you've made is replacing `addEventListener` with `onclick`, which is actually worse than the code posted in the question ?